# On clicking a url for deeplink my app showing 2 app instance on bottom

Tags: android, deep-linking, email-verification

[image: checkout the two red circles in the bottom of the screen, on clicking "**get Started**" button from email, its starting 2 instances of the App. How to avoid this, and also email verification is not completed or its not verified. how to verify the account on clicking the Get started button , immediately launching the App single instance.]

How to avoid multiple instances of the app for deep-link. and also email verification is not completed or its not verified even after clicking Get Started and choosing one of the these 2 below apps. how to verify the account on clicking the Get started button , immediately launching the App single instance.

Comment: did you write intent filter for two activities?

Comment: Multiple instances can be either multiple apps with different packageName or mutliple receivers (Activity or Intent Filters). Show us the AndroidManifest.xml file of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Probably,you declare two activities for `DeepLink` Check Your manifest file you must create two Activities with Browse able , And with Same Host and Schema. Remove Browse able tag from one of them OR change Schema.

OR

Your Device (emulator) having two application with Activity having same Host and Schema. may you have tested your code for `DeepLinking` .

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of adding the nav graph option in more than one activity
in my case:-

```
<activity
        android:name="com.aatec.bit.ui.activity.SplashScreen"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.customSplash">
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/nav_graph" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.aatec.bit.ui.activity.main_activity.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BITApp"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">


        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="bitapp-eng.github.io" />
        </intent-filter>

        <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/nav_graph" />
    </activity>
```

I just remove nav_graph from my splash screen activity

```
<activity
        android:name="com.aatec.bit.ui.activity.SplashScreen"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.customSplash">
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.aatec.bit.ui.activity.main_activity.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BITApp"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">


        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="bitapp-eng.github.io" />
        </intent-filter>

        <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/nav_graph" />
    </activity>
```